# Unable to load asset / cached image

Tags: flutter, share

My app has a button to share an image loaded from the Internet.
The code is working fine on iOS.

– But on Android, the first attempt never works. `rootBundle` throws an Exception(Unable to load asset).

The `rootBundle` only finds the cached file after a hot restart, so release versions never work.

==> If I re-run the app, the problem vanishes until the next uninstall and reinstallation of the app.

I'm using the *flutter-cache-manager* and *esys-flutter-share* packages.

I also tried Flutter Clean. Flutter Upgrade. on dev/beta/master channels.

```
shareMedia(int index) async {

    var file = await DefaultCacheManager().getSingleFile(imageLink);

    final ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load(file.path);
    await Share.file('Hi !!', 'image.png', bytes.buffer.asUint8List(), 'image/png');
  }
```

```
$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel dev, v1.10.14, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G95, locale fr-FR)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.38.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter - Unable to load asset on first load only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58578979/flutter-unable-to-load-asset-on-first-load-only)