# Flutter - Unable to load asset on first load only

Tags: image, flutter, dart

I load an image on my flutter app like this:

```
Image.asset(imageFilePath, fit: BoxFit.cover)
```

When I run the app on the emulator on the first run I get the following exception:

> I/flutter ( 7194): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE
>   ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════ I/flutter (
>   7194): The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
>   I/flutter ( 7194): Unable to load asset:
>   /data/user/0/com.example.myapp/app_flutter/888cba5135c38f7d.jpg ...

The image path is correct, and the file exists.

If I re-run the application (click the [image: play] button), the application loads without the exception and the image appears just fine.

What could be the issue?

Note:

- `flutter doctor` states everything's fine
- flutter version: v1.9.1+hotfix.2

Comment: Have you tried looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53659809/fluttererror-unable-to-load-asset)?

Comment: @tomerpacific I'm not using a static asset, it's a file saved on the documents path (`/data/user/0/com.example.myapp/app_flutter/...`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're saying that your file isn't asset, then use another Image constructor:

```dart
final img = Image.file(File(imageFilePath));
```